# Could it be a correct http query string?

Tags: http, url, char, uri, restrictions

Is there any restrictions as to which characters are allowed in URL?

For example such string:

`http://localhost:8080/auth.dll?[session_id]={762308e9-9c89-47d2-b68f-220dedd0631a}`

Could it be allowed with chars: `[, ], {, }`

?

Comment: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm#whatwhy

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[]` but not `{}`.  If you want the latter in your URL you have to encode them.  Use `%7b` in place of `{` and `%7d` in place of `}`.

That said, some browsers might not like `[]` either so you can encode them as well.  I would, however, consider why you want to use possible array delineators in a variable name and if you can avoid doing it them do so.  Even if it parses correctly there are some additional problems with the server that receives this query string.